# Некорректно завершается aiohttp-приложение при systemctl stop myapp

Tags: python-3.x, systemd

Всем привет! Имеется такая портянка:

```
from aiohttp import web
import logs

async def ws_handler(request):
   ...
   return ws

async def ws_close(app):
   logs.app_logger.info('закрываем соединения')
   for ws in app['websockets']:      
      await ws.close(code=WSCloseCode.GOING_AWAY,
                     message='Server shutdown or restart')

if __name__ == "__main__":   
   logs.app_logger.info('старт приложения')
   app = web.Application()
   app.router.add_get('/ws', ws_handler)
   app['websockets'] = []
   app.on_shutdown.append(ws_close)
   web.run_app(app)
```

logs.app_logger.info записывает сообщения в файл app.log. Запускаю портянку таким юнитом:

```
[Unit]
Description=gpro daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=www-dev
Group=users
WorkingDirectory=/home/g-project/application
ExecStart=/home/g-project/gpro-py-env/bin/python3 \
    /home/g-project/application/gpro.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID    
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Ну и, конечно, команда systemctl start gpro. Старт проходит нормально. В файле app.log вижу сообщение 'старт приложения', браузером подключаюсь к серверу, вебсокет-соединение есть. Но когда выполняю команду systemctl stop gpro, то в файле app.log не вижу сообщения 'закрываем соединения', а в браузере вместо 'Server shutdown or restart' появляется 'Обрыв соединения! Код: 1006'. Для точности добавлю, что корутина ws_close изредка всё таки срабатывает, но чаще нет. И это еще больше сбивает меня с толку. Что нужно сделать, чтобы ws_close срабатывала всегда?

Comment: Проблема сохраняется, если `TERM` поменять на `INT`?

Comment: К сожалению, да

Comment: Может в сочетании с `INT` попробовать `TimeoutStopSec=60s` указать? Или после `web.run_app(app)` попробовать добавить `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(partial(asyncio.sleep, 15)())`.

Comment: Не помогает ни то, ни другое(

Comment: Нужно перехватывать SIGINT и SIGTERM и самостоятельно обрабатывать выключение (точного кода дать не могу)

Comment: @andreymal у aiohttp на SIGINT установлен обработчик по умолчанию _вежливо_ останавливающий сервер.

Comment: Может система требует немедленного останова? Или такого не может быть? aiohttp не успевает вежливо остановить сервер, логи (loggers), которые я установил и которые должны заполняться при остановке, заполняются не полностью и к тому же не всегда.

Comment: @Александр очень похоже на то, что ваше приложение что-то убивает, не дожидаясь нормального завершения работы. Потому я и предлагал заменить `TERM` на `INT` и увеличить таймаут остановки.